# Background top-menu css color

Tags: css, colors

Css code :

```
.sf-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e9e9e9;
  background: #ffffff; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sf-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Site :

http://www.sapins-noel.fr/

Try to change background color top menu, default value is #cbccbe; (grey) i've write #ffffff (white) but nothing change, anyone have a clue ?

Comment: looking our code the background is invisible because .sf-menu doesnt have height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#header .sf-menu
```

is taking priority as it's the parent. If you really want to bypass that then -

```
.sf-menu {  
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e9e9e9;
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Good to hear, remember to use F12 (most browsers) for dev tools and then you can easily spot this yourself! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a more specific selector.

The background colour is being set with this:

```
#header .sf-menu {
    background: #cbccbe;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c1c2b4;
}
```

It looks like you are trying to change the colour with this:

```
.sf-menu {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e9e9e9;
}
```

The first selector is more specific than yours so it will take precedence.

Add `#header` in front of your selector and the specificity score will be equal. As long as your code is after the default, it will take precedence and override it.

[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I understand better, parent/child relation

Comment: It's not really anything to do with parent/child. It is the specificity of the selector that is important. Read the link I posted